# set width elements in divs

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs: 2 of them in a row and the third underneath them. 
I want the right down TextBox with above TextBox to be coordinated.

Do you have a solution?

Many thanks!

```css
.form-group {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height:50px;
}
    .form-group label {
        float:left;
        width: 130px;
    }
    .form-group input {
        float:left;
        width: 230px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="family">Family</label>
    <input id="family" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="width:100%;">
    <label for="address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" style="width:67%"/>
</div>
```

It looks ok on a full page: http://aug.imghost.us/QWQo.jpg but when the page size is changed the boxed don't align nicely: http://aug.imghost.us/QWRO.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="family">Family</label>
    <input id="family" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="width:90%;">
    <label for="address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" />
</div>

<style>
.form-group {
float: left;
width: 40%;
height:50px;
margin: 0 5%;
}
.form-group label {
float:left;
width: 135px;
}
.form-group input {
float:left;
width: calc(100% - 135px);
}
</style>
```

Comment: I will be very grateful if you vote up my answer :) Or select as "best answer"

Answer (score 0):

remove the inline style you have applied on the address `input` and change the css as following -

```
.form-group {
float: left;
width: 50%;
height:50px;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding-right: 20px;
}
.form-group label {
    float:left;
    width: 130px;
}
.form-group input {
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(100% - 130px); /* supported in latest browsers */
}
```

[check out the compatible browsers for `calc`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) - http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnhuboh1/)

An alternative solution will be to use `tables` of 4 columns and then `colspan` the last address `input` to 3. I think, this one would be the best solution as it will be compatible with older browsers also.

Comment: Thank you for the perfect answer.